# asm8086 about printing a string

Tags: string, assembly

hello in my code I want to print on the screen a specific string with the following interrupt

```
lea dx, pkey
mov ah, 9
int 21h
```

and afterwards I want to print another string, but I want the emulator to delete the previous string.
For instance if I want to print:

```
"Hello and welcome"
```

and afterwards I want to print:

```
"Press here to continue"
```

I want the screen to be empty from other strings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like there are a lot of things you want. ;) Did you make any attempts at a solution you can share? Exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: @lurker I really don't know how to be more exact :/ I just need the screen to be empty from other strings when I want to print something else

Comment: The mechanism for clearing the screen is dependent on your output system. There's not enough information here to even guess what you might need to do.

Comment: @HoboSapiens what do you mean by output system?

Comment: If my answer helped you, you may mark it as the right one or upvote it (or both!).

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I marked it. Btw, in a maze, when my object faces a wall, how do I make the object not go over the wall and wait for another input?

Comment: You need an array variable to hold the x,y positions of the walls, then you compare the x,y position of your object with the x,y positions of the walls.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez can you show me an example of the code?

Comment: Got an idea. Post another question so I will have more room to post the code, because these comments are not big enough. And make your question full of details about your maze, adding an image will help me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mchlsn, what you need is to clear the screen between the first string and the second. Using 8086 this would be the code, copy and paste it in you assembler compiler, I used EMU8086 :

```
.stack 100h
.data
hello db 'Hello and welcome$'
press db 'Press here to continue$'
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

  lea dx, hello ;DISPLAY FIRST STRING.
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h

  call wait_for_key
  call clear_screen

  lea dx, press ;DISPLAY SECOND STRING.
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h

  call wait_for_key

;FINISH THE PROGRAM PROPERLY.
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h           

proc wait_for_key
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h
  ret
endp

proc clear_screen
  mov  ah,0
  mov  al,7
  int  10H
  ret
endp
```

Hope it helps.

By the way, in the procedure clear_screen, if the value al = 7 gives you any problem, you can try other numbers from 0 to 7.

Comment: your solution seems to work. al=3 made it work for me and not al=7. Thank you very much.